# Stop the execution for a period of time in java

Tags: java, android

Hello i am making a quiz game and i have a problem i will try to discribe in a simplier way below.I have a question and 4 buttons each one represents an answer.When i click an answer i want the chosen button to change color to orange for 2 seconds and then goes green if the answer is correct and red if the answer is wrong and the correct answer going green too and stays to this situation for another 2 seconds before bring the new question and all the buttons take their previous(defaut) color.

I have tried many ways like `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);` , `Thread.sleep(2000);` and some more but the changes appears after that period of time.When i need to appears now and for the next 2 seconds.

Last way i tried is a timer like this :

```
     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endTime = startTime + 2*1000; // 2 seconds * 1000 ms/sec
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)
    {

    }
```

to stop the execution into the while loop for 2 seconds.
I made a simplier application with one button to describe the problem in the forum.I want when i click the button the button's color change to red for 2 seconds and then took the previous color again.
Here is the java code :

```
package com.example.sakis.fillbutton;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button but;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorbut);


}




public void ClickButton(View view )  {




    but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.initcolor);

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endTime = startTime + 2*1000; // 2 seconds * 1000 ms/sec
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)
    {

    }


   but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorbut);

}
```

}

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sakis.fillbutton.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:onClick="ClickButton"
    style="@style/ButtonAnswer"/>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {}
```

Busy loops are **THE BAD THING**. Never do that. [Wiki quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting):

> In general [...] spinning is considered an anti-pattern and
>   should be avoided, **as processor time that could be used to execute
>   a different task is instead wasted on useless activity**.

Back to the question:

> When i click an answer i want the chosen button to change color to orange for 2 seconds and then goes green if the answer is correct and red if the answer

You can use `Runnable` and post it with required delay, w/o need to worry too much. When delay pass, your `Runnable` will be handled. Simply add this to your class members:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

and then create and post said runnable with handling delayed as much as needed:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        changesColorsToGreenOrRed();
    }
};
mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
```

> and stays to this situation for another 2 seconds before bring the new question

The `changesColorsToGreenOrRed()` should do its job and then simply post another `Runnable`.

Comment: Answer is obviously correct, but would be improved by an explanation of why busy loops are bad.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting "In general, however, spinning is considered an anti-pattern and should be avoided as processor time that could be used to execute a different task is instead wasted on useless activity."

Comment: The answer is working for the simple example but how should i edit my code when i need to change to a third color for another 2 seconds?For example from my default button color to orange and then from orange to green or red?

Comment: In general nothing prevents you to post another Runnable. If you got more  "steps" then you need to just think about approach, to avoid having tons of methods  calling each other. Maybe you need method that accepts `color` as argument to keep the code reused? Also note that runnable can post itself when needed too, so if you want you can even "tick" that way by firing runnable that increments/changes i.e. class member and then runs itself again

Comment: What i mean and using as example the simple code with the one button i posted below.How am i going from red to green for 2 seconds and then again from green to orange for example?

Comment: As I said. Post another delayed runnable **from the code** invoked by the first runnable (or from the runnable directly).

Comment: Can you please give an example how to post another runnable invoked by the first one?

Comment: Like that: `mHandler.postDelayed(anotherRunnable, 2000);` and of course you need to construct it first the same way as in my answer

Comment: You should not edit the question further. You asked, you got it answered. Done. It's read only for you now (posting comments is fine though). I rolled back your last edit. As for the code you posted there - no - it was not correct. Both `Runnables` were the same (so were you wanted to set another color)? But assuming that's easy to correct, just move creation and posting of **second** runnable into `run()` method of 1st, so you will have 2nd one posted once 1st fires and completes.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your patient and support.It is finally working.